# How to initialize array that declared inside struct?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization, embedded

I was developing C program to read status of door access. I created a struct in which two arrays were declared. I wanted to initialize the array at the time of definition of that structure.
For example,

Struct declaration in .h file:

```
typedef volatile struct
{

    uint8_t __near const * const people_in_input_ports[8];

    uint8_t __near const * const people_out_input_ports[8];

}GATE_ACCESS_CTRL_BLOCK;
```

Struct definition in .c file:

```
GATE_ACCESS_CTRL_BLOCK g_gate_acc_parameters    = { 
    .people_in_input_ports  = {&P12, &P4, &P4, &P4, &P6, &P6, &P6, &P6},                                                
    .people_out_input_ports = {&P14, &P14, &P2, &P14, &P14, &P5, &P5, &P1}
};
```

Here, `P12`, `P4`, `P6`, `P5`, `P2` and `P14` are sfr addresses of corresponding port.

I got the following error.

```
E0520029:Expected an expression
E0520029:Expected an expression
```

How to initialize arrays that are declared inside of a structure by using arrays' name?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

In my project the C90 standard was selected which doesn't support that kind of initialization in the compiler settings. Changing it to the C99 standard makes it work.

Comment: Or just drop the designated initializers.